# Pass object to controller without using form helpers in Playframework 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In Playframework 2.0 can we pass objects without using form helpers?

For e.g.,

```
class User {
     Address address;
}
```

In ui: `<input type="text" name="address"/> //HELP NEEDED HERE`

How can I get the address object into the controller without using form helpers?

Please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you format a bit the code and the question because it's a bit difficult to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the form helpers per se. It should suffice to make the fields of your classes public. The form itself should look like this (assuming this is a more or less standard user/address scenario):

classes:

```
public class User {

 public String name;
 public String phonenumber;

 public Address address;
}

public class Address {
 public String street;
 public String city;
}
```

Form fields:

```
<input type="text" name="address.street" />
<input type="text" name="address.city" />

<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="phonenumber" />
```

you should then be able to use form(User.class) and its .bindFromRequest() to get a Form which you can validate / use. See also the [official documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaForms) on that feature.

The important thing is that your form field names match the field names of your classes and that the fields are accessible, so the data binder can populate the created instances with the data from the form.